# Install only the required packages that are not on a different machine

Tags: python, django, pip

I have cloned my Django project from GitHub to my different machine. The other machine already has some of the latest python packages installed (eg Django v1.10.6), whereas in the *requirements.txt* file of the GitHub project it has different versions of the package (eg Django v1.10.5). Now when I run this command

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

It installs the version that's in the *requirements.txt* file. I know this is not a good idea because some of the code may not work because of version changes, but I need to learn as how can I install only the required packages that are not on my other machine or install the latest packages?

Comment: You can use virtualenv to create a virtual python environment for the cloned project. Install required dependencies only in environment.

Comment: Did you get any resolution on this one?

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect scenario for using virtualenv

```
$ [sudo] pip install virtualenv
```

then

```
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```